# why doesnt my label appear in my tkinter window when i use the RAISED relief but does appear when i use another relief?

Tags: python, tkinter

```
from tkinter import *

window = Tk()
window.geometry("300x300")
window.config(background="red")
window.title("label")

photo = PhotoImage(file='photo_1.png')

label = Label(window,
              text="hello world",
              font=('Arial',40,"bold"),
              fg="black",
              bg="yellow",
              relief=RAISED,

              bd=10,
              padx=20,
              pady=20,
              image=photo,
              compound='bottom')`

label.pack()

window.mainloop()
```

when i use the `RAISED` relief, my label doesnt appear in my tkinter window. but when i change it to `SUNKEN` or `FLAT` relieves, it does appear.

Comment: For me every thing is working file. I believe `Label` is not shown cuz of image. Can you provide that image?

Comment: I've run your code with multiple images and I can see no problem!?

Comment: What platform are you running on? I'm guessing OSX.

Comment: yes, i am working on OSX